ConTeXt won't find my fonts
I would like to use my own local fonts in my ConTeXt documents. They are stored in /usr/local/share/fonts/ like so:
├── cooper
│   ├── Cooper-BlackItalic.otf
│   ├── ...
├── Vollkorn
│   ├── Vollkorn-BlackItalic.otf
│   ├── ...
├── ... 

I've followed the instructions given in the "Use the fonts you want" page of the ConTeXt Garden, namely:

Set the OSFONTDIR environment variable to my font folder path:
$ export OSFONTDIR=/usr/local/share/fonts

Run the following commands:
$ mtxrun --generate
$ mtxrun --script fonts --reload


Even after that, running
mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern='*cooper*'

returns nothing. Trying to use them in a document also causes it to fallback to the default Latin Modern font. What am I doing wrong?
I've installed ConTeXt via texlive 2024, the following versions:
$ context --version
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.06
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2024.02.27 09:18
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkxl/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2024.02.27 09:18

$ mtxrun --version
mtxrun          | ConTeXt TDS Runner Tool 1.32
mtxrun          | source path

Update:
I can see the fonts from my $OSFONTDIR listed in the names.tma file, located in ~/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luametatex-cache/context/<random chars>/fonts/data/. But still they don't get listed by mtxrun --script fonts --list --all.

Welcome! To me it looks like you have done what one should, at least for the standalone installation. Maybe things work differently in a tex live installation.

I've had exactly this same issue, with even the exact same fonts. I seem to remember that the solution is to rename the files/folders so that everything is lowercase, but I'll see if I can find my exact solution and write a full answer later.

Removing the TeX Live installation of ConTeXt and reinstalling it from ConTeXt Garden solved the issue.
If anyone is able to provide a fix for the original problem, that is, making local fonts work with TeX Live's ConTeXt, I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted solution.

I just tried with files from

https://fontsgeek.com/fonts/Cooper-Black-Italic
https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/80261/cooper-black

Stored in /usr/local/share/fonts/
$ tree  /usr/local/share/fonts/

/usr/local/share/fonts/
├── cooper
│   ├── Cooper Black Italic.otf
│   └── CooperBlack.otf
└── Vollkorn
    ├── Vollkorn-BlackItalic.ttf
    ├── Vollkorn-Black.ttf
    ├── ...

$ ls -la   /usr/local/share/fonts/cooper 
total 92
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 20 juil. 10:15  .
drwxrwsr-x 4 root staff  4096 20 juil. 10:15  ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  42256 20 juil. 10:15 'Cooper Black Italic.otf'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  37448 20 juil. 10:15  CooperBlack.otf

then I check :
$ echo $OSFONTDIR
/home/username/.fonts:/usr/share/fonts:/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/:/usr/local/share/fonts

And finally :
$  mtxrun --version
mtxrun          | ConTeXt TDS Runner Tool 1.32
mtxrun          | source path

$ mtxrun --generate
$ mtxrun --script fonts --reload
$ mtxrun --script fonts --list --all --pattern='*cooper*'
identifier                   familyname     fontname                     filename   subfont   instances

cooperblack                  cooperblack    cooperblack                  /usr/local/share/fonts/cooper/CooperBlack.otf
cooperblackbold              cooperblack    cooperblack                  /usr/local/share/fonts/cooper/CooperBlack.otf
cooperblackitalic            cooperblack    cooperblackitalic            /usr/local/share/fonts/cooper/Cooper Black Italic.otf
cooperblackregular           cooperblack    cooperblack                  /usr/local/share/fonts/cooper/CooperBlack.otf
cooperhewittbold             cooperhewitt   cooperhewittbold             /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cooperhewitt/CooperHewitt-Bold.otf
...
cooperhewittthinitalic       cooperhewitt   cooperhewittthinitalic       /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cooperhewitt/CooperHewitt-ThinItalic.otf

Maybe to check :

echo $OSFONTDIR
read access to the font files
provide web link to the font files you are actually using, to reproduce


Thank you for the detailed investigation. I don't think the fonts themselves are the issue; I picked those two as exemples because they are free and open fonts (here are the pages for Vollkorn and Cooper). I've been using them all in LuaLaTeX for quite a while, without issues.
As to ConTeXt-specific issues: echoing $OSFONTDIR shows me the variable was set correctly. At some point I might try installing ConTeXt from the official website, not from TeX Live, and see if it solves it.

Ah, and I know ConTeXt is looking in the right place because I can see all my fonts listed in the names.tda file (located in ~/.texlive2024/texmf-var/luametatex-cache/context/<random chars>/fonts/data). But when I issue the mtxrun --script fonts --list --all command, they're not there, and trying to use them in a document leads to an error.
